# DB driver is not found when running in docker swarm

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker-compose

I have a Spring boot application running with maven. I can successfully run my app locally, but when I run an image in the local docker swarm: `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml compose` I get the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver`

I've checked env.getPropertySources():

```
compose_service@debian| spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
compose_service@debian| spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/service
compose_service@debian| spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

These props work fine with local running.
I've checked, the built jar contains the Postgres lib; maven dependency in my project:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I recently ran the app with `docker-compose up` and it also worked, so it seems like a problem with running in swarm. Any ideas?

Comment: did you add this property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect in application.properties?

Comment: @mystery yes, it is here. Please check my post, props sample was already there

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't add secrets to docker swarm by `echo`,
which adds \n to each string (that's why my driver name wasn't valid).

Instead, I should use printf:

```
printf "org.postgresql.Driver" | docker secret create db-driver -
```

Hope it will save time for someone